# ipmitool and ALOM (Sun T2000)

Tags: sun, ipmitool

```
ipmitool -vv -I lan -H srv-alom -U admin sdr
ipmitool -vv -I lanplus -H srv-alom -U admin sdr
```

or

```
ipmitool -vv -I lan -H srv-alom -U admin sensor
ipmitool -vv -I lanplus -H srv-alom -U admin sensor
```

i get this error:

```
Querying SDR for sensor list
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[0], open=[268000]
IPMI LAN host 10.173.0.15 port 623
Sending IPMI/RMCP presence ping packet
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1], open=[268000]
  No response from remote controller
Get Auth Capabilities command failed
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1], open=[268000]
  No response from remote controller
Get Auth Capabilities command failed
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
ipmi_lan_send_cmd failed to open intf
Get Device ID command failed
Unable to open SDR for reading
```

but i can ping this machine.

Can somebody help me?
ipmitool version 1.8.8

must i configure the ALOM for IPMI?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while looking information about how to solve the same problem. After some research, I don't believe the ALOM supports IPMI (just ssh and snmp traps).

See [This Oracle docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19118-01/n1.sprovsys52/819-6519/auto31/index.html) for more info.